# nothing happens after react-native run-ios --device in react native

Tags: react-native, device, react-native-ios

running on my device used to work fine. However, suddenly,
when I run react-native run-ios --device,
I get to the ending like

- [[ true != true ]]

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

installing and launching your app on User’s iPhone...

However, nothing happens after and the app does not get installed in my device.

Comment: for ios i would recommend launching app directly from xcode instead of command line

Comment: directly from xcode does the same thing. NOthing happens after buidling even though it succeeds

Comment: does the metro bundler opens and have you trusted your computer in your iphone and lastly is the app atleast installed in the iphone or none of them happens ?

Comment: the app does not get installed. I just checked, and other apps I create from xcode works fine so it has something to do with the react native compiler

Comment: yeah I used xcode instead of terminal and nothing gets installed either

Comment: can you try restarting your xcode and closing all metro bundlers

Comment: I already tried that several times

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the following worked a while back when I faced a similar issue:

```
>npm install -g ios-deploy 

>react-native run-ios --device "My iPhone"
```

Answer (score 8):

I **seriously** offer you to install `ios-deploy` by using `brew`:

```sh
brew install ios-deploy
```

If you installed it by `npm` before installing by `brew` uninstall it by the following command:

```sh
sudo npm uninstall -g ios-deploy
```

After having the correct version with the correct installation plug your device and then run the below command:

```sh
npx react-native run-ios --device
```

This current command directly installs the app on the first plugged device to your macOS system. if you plugged several devices then you should pass the name of a targeted device just like below:

```sh
npx react-native run-ios --device "DeviceName"
```

Comment: This does not list my device

Comment: No iOS devices connected.

Comment: I tried all kinds of stuff around re-installing the XCode command line tools and such as mentioned in other answers but THIS was it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to have your device connected! ‍♂️